# why does my program keep giving 'cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called' error?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, subclass

I am trying to create a class where there is always exactly one player, and zero or more enemies. Both have
“hit points” (the amount of health the combatant has). When the hit points become zero or lower, the combatant is
removed from the board. Health potions can increase the player’s hit points, while traps lower the player’s hit points.
Combatants have attacks which vary in strength. There are minimum and maximum attack values. Each time an attack
is made, a new random attack value between the minimum and maximum is returned. This amount of health is removed
from the combatant that is being attacked.

I defined an **abstract Combatant** class that is a subaclass of **Content**. It had:

Three instance variables:

**int** values for the health, and minimum and maximum attack values.

And a constructor which accepts parameters of type **(String, int, int, int)** which are the symbol, health,
minimum, and maximum attack points, in that order.

Then I implemented 3 methods:

**int getHP()** – returns the current number of hit points (health)

**int doAttack()** – return a random number between the minimum and maximum attack values,
inclusive. Investigate **Math.random()** to do this.

**void changeHP()** – add this amount to the combatant’s hit points. The number could be negative.

I define three subclasses of **Combatant**:

**Player**: represented by an “@” on the board, this is the playing piece the user will be able to move. The player
should start with 100 hit points, and have a minimum attack value of 5, and a maximum of 10.

**Troll**: represented by a “t” on the board. Trolls should start with 10 hit points, and have a minimum attack
value of 1, and a maximum of 10.

**GreaterTroll**, which is a **subclass** of Troll: Greater Trolls have double the hit points of **Troll**s, attack twice
not once, and are represented by a “T” on the board. The constructor of **GreaterTroll** should call the
constructor of **Troll**, then modify the hit points. The **doAttack()** method of GreaterTroll should call the
**doAttack()** method in **Troll** twice, and return the total damage.

These three subclasses should have only a no-parameters constructor.

This is my code below:

```
public abstract class Combatants extends Content{
  private int healthValue;
  private int minHit;
  private int maxHit;

  public Combatants(String sss, int HV, int min, int max){
    super(sss);
    healthValue = HV;
    minHit = min;
    maxHit = max;
  }

  public int getHP(){
    return healthValue;
  }

  public int doAttack(int attack){
    attack = (int)(Math.random() * maxHit + minHit);
    return attack;
  }

  public void changeHP(int attack){
    if(attack > 0) {
        healthValue = Math.max(healthValue - attack, 0);
    }

  }



  class Player extends Combatants{
    public Player(){
      super("@", 100, 10, 5);
    }
  }

  class Troll extends Combatants{
    public Troll(){
      super("t", 10, 10, 1);
    }
  }

  class GreaterTroll extends Troll{
    public GreaterTroll(){
      super();
    }
  }
}
```

It keeps on giving me 'cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called' error.

Can anyone please tell me why?

You can test it with this main class code:

```
public class TestPhase3 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Tile[][] board = {
    {new Wall(), new  Wall(), new Wall(), new Wall(),  new Wall(), new Wall()},
    {new Wall(), new  OpenSpace(new Trap()),  new  OpenSpace(new Amulet()), new OpenSpace(), new OpenSpace(new Troll()), new Wall()},
    {new Wall(), new OpenSpace(new  Trap()), new OpenSpace(new HealthPotion()), new OpenSpace(new Player()), new OpenSpace(), new Wall()},
    {new Wall(), new  Wall(), new Wall(), new Wall(), new Wall(), new Wall()},
  };

  for (Tile[] row : board) {
   for (Tile t: row) {
    System.out.print(t.getSymbol());
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for `Content`?  Also we need the code for `Tile`, `Wall`, `OpenSpace`, etc. or we can't run your test code at all.  Please see how to create an MCVE and then test the code you post to make sure it really does compile, as the instructions say. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In your code, the 3 subclasses are *inner* classes of `Combatants`. Either move them outside, or make them `static`, so they are nested but not inner classes.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, your method worked. 